# Is there a statistical measure that combines difference in means and dispersion?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, metric, rating

I am working on an academic physics problem, where I am trying to determine favourable variables in two data sets, where both data sets have the same variables.

The most favourable variables would have the highest difference in means and a small dispersion of data - a small 'spread'.

Is there a statistical measure/metric that combines both the difference in means and dispersion of data in this way?

Comment: A standardised effect size like Cohen's d is probably what you want. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d

Comment: This page on standardised effects has more discussion. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Difference_family:_Effect_sizes_based_on_differences_between_means

Comment: And t-statistic (from two sample t.test) may fit your goal.

Comment: It sounds like what you want would be two narrow peaks (one per group) separated by a great distance. Is that about right?

Comment: Hi Dave, that's exactly what I am after. But I need some metric/quantitative method of working out which of the variables offers two narrow peaks that have the greatest difference in their means.

Comment: This is a *valuation* problem: one in which you must make a trade-off between an increased difference in means and a decrease in dispersion. Accepting some solution that has been used in other applications would amount to supposing *your* values are comparable to those of the other applications--which, even if plausible, ought to be checked. The most general solution will be of the form $\alpha f(m)-\beta g(d)$ where $f$ and $g$ are non-decreasing functions, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-negative numbers, and $m$ is the mean difference and $d$ is some measurement of the dispersion.

Comment: (Continued) In light of this, what information can you add to your question that will help us understand, *quantitatively,* how you value these potential trade-offs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standardised effect sizes scale the difference between groups by the variance within each group.  Cohen's $d$ is probably the simplest and most widely used.  Cohen's $d$ is also sometimes called the 'standardised mean difference'.

To calculate it simply divide the difference in means between the groups by the pooled standard deviation estimated within the groups.

Note this is different to the t-statistic which is the difference in means divided by the standard error of the difference in means.  This will depend heavily on sample size (bigger sample sizes will lead to higher t-statistics), while Cohen's d will not depend on sample size (except that it becomes more precisely estimated as sample size increases).

Comment: Thanks George. This is exactly what I am after.

Comment: No problem.  @whuber makes an interesting point in the comments though.